# Is there a shorter way of saying "travelers on the road to self discovery"?

Tags: single-word-requests

As in the exclamation, "Calling all travelers on the road to self discovery."

Comment: Calling all [self-seekers](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/self-seeking)? ;) All [omphaloskeptics](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/omphaloskepsis)?

Comment: *introspective* people...

Comment: I think there is a mythical [*destination*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shambhala) for such a journey; [*Shambala*](https://youtu.be/xnyh6i9NvmE).

Comment: Autonauts!  Transcend and rise up!

Comment: Calling thrill seekers! Adventurers on a spiritual quest!

Answer (score 1):

*wayward, soul seekers*

> Those who are wayward in spirit will gain understanding; those who complain will accept instruction." –[Isaiah 29:24](http://biblehub.com/isaiah/29-24.htm)

"Calling all wayward, soul seekers!"

If this is a speech at a graduation, stick with the original. *Wayward* captures the "self discovery" bit, or perhaps the *need* thereof, but it's pretty condescending and I had to cherry-pick this definition:

*wayward*, adjective –[MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wayward)

> not following a rule or regular course of action
>   *A wayward throw broke the window.*